# Making large SQL query efficicent

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on a rather complex query.

I'm looking to write a query that shows the "top five customers" as well as some key metrics (counts with conditions) about each of those customers. Each of the different metrics uses a totally different join structure.

```
+-----------+------------+   +-----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+
| customer  |            |   | metricn   |            |    | metricn_lineitem       | 
+-----------+------------+   +-----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+
| id        | Name       |   | id        | customer_id|    |id         |metricn_id  |
| 1         | Customer1  |   | 1         | 1          |    | 1         | 1          |
| 2         | Customer2  |   | 2         | 2          |    | 2         | 1          |
+-----------+------------+   +-----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+
```

The issue this is that I always want to group by this customer table.

I first tried to put all of my joins into the original query, but the query was abysmal with performance. I then tried using subqueries, but I couldn't get them to group by the original hospital id.

Here's a sample query

```
SELECT 
     customer.name, 

     (SELECT COUNT(metric1_lineitem.id) 
      FROM metric1 INNER JOIN metric1_lineitem 
      ON metric1_lineitem.metric1_id = metric1.id
      WHERE metric1.customer_id = customer_id
      ) as metric_1,

     (SELECT COUNT(metric2_lineitem.id) 
      FROM metric2 INNER JOIN metric2_lineitem 
      ON metric2_lineitem.metric2_id = metric2.id
      WHERE metric2.customer_id = customer_id
      ) as metric_2

FROM customer
GROUP BY customer.name
SORT BY COUNT(metric1.id) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, metric_1, metric_2
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS metric_1
           FROM metric1 AS m
           INNER JOIN metric1_lineitem AS l ON m.id = l.metric1_id
           GROUP BY customer_id) m1
ON m1.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS metric_2
           FROM metric2 AS m
           INNER JOIN metric2_lineitem AS l ON m.id = l.metric2_id
           GROUP BY customer_id) m1
ON m2.customer_id = c.customer_id
ORDER BY metric_1 DESC
LIMIT 5
```

You should also avoid using `COUNT(columnname)` when you can use `COUNT(*)` instead. The former has to test every value to see if it's null.

Comment: I don't know about mysql, but in sql server this will most likely speed it up as correlated subqueries are basically cursors that process row by row and this is a set-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although your data structure may be lousy, your query may not be so bad, with two exceptions.  I don't think you need the aggregation on the outer level.  Also, the "correlation"s in the `where` clause (such as `metric1.customer_id = customer_id`) are not doing anything, because `customer_id` is coming from the local tables.  You need `metric1.customer_id = c.customer_id`:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(metric1_lineitem.id) 
        FROM metric1 INNER JOIN
             metric1_lineitem 
             ON metric1_lineitem.metric1_id = metric1.id
        WHERE metric1.customer_id = c.customer_id
      ) as metric_1,
      (SELECT COUNT(metric2_lineitem.id) 
       FROM metric2 INNER JOIN
            metric2_lineitem 
            ON metric2_lineitem.metric2_id = metric2.id
       WHERE metric2.customer_id = c.customer_id
      ) as metric_2
FROM customer c
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

How can you make this run faster?  One way is to introduce indexes.  I would recommend `metric1(customer_id)`, `metric2(customer_id)`, `metric1_lineitem(metric1_id)` and `metric2_lineitem(metric2_id)`.

This may be faster than the aggregation method (proposed by Barmar) because MySQL is inefficient with aggregations.  This should allow the aggregations to take place only using indexes instead of the base tables.